# How do I get a program to calculate the pay raise for each employee from a file?

Tags: python, file

Here is the problem I am trying to solve for my introduction to programming course:

The trustees of a small college are considering voting a pay raise for their faculty
members. They want to grant a 7 percent raise for those earning more than $50,000.00,
a 4 percent raise for those earning more than $60,000.00 and 5.5 percent raise for all
others. However before doing so, they want to know how much this will cost. Write a
program that will print the pay raise for each faculty member, the total amount of the
raises, and the average of the raises. Also, print the total faculty payroll before and after
the raise. Use the end of file as a sentinel value.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
def main():

    inFile = open('program7.txt', 'r')
    total = 0
    newSalaryTotal = 0
    lineRead = inFile.readline()
    while lineRead != '':
       words = lineRead.split() 
       for word in words:
           salary = float(word)
           print(format(salary, '.2f'))
       if salary > 60000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.04
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           total = total + salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
       elif salary > 50000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.07
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           total = total + salary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
       elif salary < 50000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.055
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           total = total + salary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
       lineRead = inFile.readline()

    print('The total is: ', format(total, '.2f'))
    print('The new salary total is: ', format(newSalaryTotal, '.2f'))
    # Close the file.
    inFile.close()


main()`
```

I am struggling to get the output to display the pay raise for each of the employees after reading the data from the file. I also don't know how to set up the variables necessary to calculate the average of the raises. Any help that can be offered will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is the output that is being given from the code I provided above. What I am asking is why the original salary and pay raise aren't being printed for each value that is being read from the file? I have also provided the data that is in the text file below:

Input Data "program7.txt":

52500.00       64029.50      56000.00      50001.00
65500.00       42800.00      45000.50      68900.00
60000.00       59999.94      54120.25      64100.00
44000.50       80100.20      90000.00      41000.00
60500.50       72000.00      50000.01      50000.00
80001.75       60001.00

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyQWW.png)

Answer (score 0):

For now i will avoid looking at how you display the pay raises of each employees as your print statements appear to do that already? Without your 'program7.txt' file i cant see what is actually being produced though so perhaps you can edit the question to describe your current and desired outputs.

Instead I'll forcus on helping you calcualte the averages. Your problem is somewhat ill defined as there are multiple ways of calcualting 'the average of the raises'. To illustrate this consider the following input data.

```
+-------+--------+-------+------------+ 
| Name  | Salary | Raise | New Salary |
+-------+--------+-------+------------+
| Bob   | 100000 |  4%   |     104000 |
| Sally |  40000 |  5.5% |      42200 |
| Dave  |  55000 |  7%   |      58850 |
+-------+--------+-------+------------+
| Total | 195000 | 10050 |     205050 |
+-------+--------+-------+------------+
```

The first possibility is to calculate the **average raise per person** by adding the raises as percentages and then dividing by the number of people i.e.

(4% + 5% + 7%) / 3 = 16%/3 = 5.333%

Alternativly you could calculate the **average raise as a function of total cost** by adding the raises and divided by old salaries. i.e.

10050 / 195000 = 5.154%

Both of these are 'correct'

For the first method you will need to add a variable for number of employees.

For the second method you can calculate the total raise required by subtracting `total` from `newSalaryTotal`

edit: All salaries from your input data are being brought in as a single line.

At the moment your if statements only runs on the final 'word' in each line.  In your case you probably want it to trigger once per word. To do this you need to indent the if statement to be included in the for loop as follows

```
   for word in words:
       salary = float(word)
       print(format(salary, '.2f'))
       if salary > 60000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.04
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           total = total + salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
       elif salary > 50000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.07
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           total = total + salary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
       elif salary < 50000.0:
           newSalary = salary * 1.055
           newSalaryTotal += newSalary
           total = total + salary
           payRaise = newSalary - salary
           print('The original salary is: ', salary)
           print('The pay raise is: ', payRaise)
   lineRead = inFile.readline()
```

alternativly you could leave your program unchanged and instead edit your input data so that each salary was brought in on a new line rather than just being seperated by a space. i.e. as [program7_2.txt](https://pastebin.com/DQtCM1wi)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited my original post to show the output given by the program as well as the input data in the file. My desired output is to have the program read each value in the file and print the original salary and pay raise. I think once I get that sorted out I can figure out the average with the two options you mentioned above. Thanks again for any additional help you can offer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, indenting the if statements fixed my problem. I will try to finish the program tonight, but I think it should be pretty smooth from here